# Force an IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

One of my past exam paper questions requires me to modify a method in such a way that an IllegalArgumentException occurs.

The method simply involves withdrawing money from a bank account balance

Here is the method that does this.

`public void withdraw( double ammount )
    {
        this.balance -= ammount;
    }`

How can I modify this method to make this exception occur? I've never seen this exception before.

Answer (score 2):

An exception can be thrown with `throw`:

```
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Amount must be positive.");
```

You should write the rest of the method yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To throw an exception, you use the throw command, then pass an instance of an Exception (exceptions are classes too).

Like this:

```
throw e;
```

Where `e` is an exception. This syntaxis the same for Java and C#.

So if you want to throw an IllegalArgumentException, first create an instance, then throw it.

```
public void withdraw(double amount)
{
    if (this.balance < amount)
    {
        IllegalArgumentException iae =
            new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid amount. You're broke.");
        throw iae;
    }
    else this.balance -= amount;
}
```

Next step, go read about try-catch-finally blocks.

Comment: I'm not trying to throw the exception, I'm trying to make the IllegalArgumentException error occur. As in, if you got an ArrayOutOfBoundsException, the Console will display in red text that you've got this exception.